# How can I fail a Jenkins Maven release if it contains SNAPSHOT in the pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

When we do a release we want to fail the **release** if any of the dependent apps are still in SNAPSHOT version in the pom. For normal builds this should be allowed.

I guess there might be 2 options:

- Is there a maven switch for the jenkins maven plugin to specify such and option?
- Run a bash script to check for "SNAPSHOT" string in pom.xml, but then how can I detect "if this is a release" inside a jenkins job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html) to perform a release, it will fail the release in case of SNAPSHOT dependencies.

You also can specify checking for [timestamped SNAPSHOT dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#allowTimestampedSnapshots), by default it is `false`.

Comment: We are currently are using the maven Release plugin, however we have had a case or two now where it did release with a snapshot. I will try the timestamped option as well, thanks

Comment: Also, how can I check if one of our own apps is a dependency, but I need to check if it is in SNAPSHOT before the release is done?

Comment: What do you mean by "our own apps"? If it is a module of the same maven project, then everything will be resolved correctly. If it is a separate project, then for maven there is no different if it is your or external dependency. Could you please describe your case more detailed?